# PHP convert_uudecode function - special characters problem

Tags: apostrophe, quotation-marks

I'd like to use convert_uudecode function, but encoded string contains a quotation mark ( " ) and also an apostrophe ( ' )

I can't just do it like this:

```
print convert_uudecode("M:'1T<#HO+V1N87=R;W0N;F%Z=V$N<&PO;&EC96YC97,O8F5S="UD96%L'0` ` ");
```

cos as you can see there is already a quotation mark.

I also cant do it this way:

```
print convert_uudecode('M:'1T<#HO+V1N87=R;W0N;F%Z=V$N<&PO;&EC96YC97,O8F5S="UD96%L'0` ` ');
```

becouse rendered string also contains an apostrophe.

Any help?
Regards, 
David

Comment: I've managed this by dividing this string into 3 different strings so I can join it while calling a convert_uudecode(); Maybe it can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange each Apostrophe ' inside the string with  `&apos;`
and for each Quotation mark " you need to use  `&quot;`

An another alternative is to replace the " with \" and ' with \'

**Visit this link below:**

*Hexadecimal value, Entity encoding etc*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544%28v=sql.80%29.aspx